# How do I identify a collision with a specific body?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

How can I identify when the ground body collides with another b2Body? I can use `b2ContactListener` to be notified of collision events, but how do I tell which bodies collided?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic Box2D collision detection](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/basic-box2d-collision-detection)

Comment: @Byte56, nope..see here I don't know how to find collision with groundBody and there its different. Please write answer if you know how to identify collision when object hits ground floor.

Comment: even I used b2ContactListener, that helped me to identify collision with other b2body but not with groundBody..so your link is not helped.

Comment: @Byte56: Not a duplicate, but the question needed more explanation. Downvoters please reconsider.

Comment: @Byte56 Joe Wreschnig, I don't mind if you people vote up or down...now I got solution from Joe Wreschnig. Really 'Helping hands are better than praying Lips'..thanks alot for your answer. Now resolved all problem in game..

Comment: @SaveWater Indeed they are. I'm glad you got the answer you wanted. Do try to be a bit clearer next time. I'm sure you can see the difference between your original question and Joe's edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the point of b2Body's `UserData` member. It's a pointer you can set to anything you want. During the collision you can check this pointer and change how you react to the collision depending on its value.

For a trivial case, you can make the user data a NSString. For example,

```
groundBody->SetUserData(@"Ground Body");
```

Then inside your `b2ContactListener` subclass, or when you loop over bodies checking their contact points, you can use:

```
if ([bodyA->GetUserData() isEqual:@"Ground Body"]) {
    // Do something special if the body is the ground body.
}
```

(n.b. This is not compatible with ARC. I wouldn't recommend using ARC with games yet if you're an Objective-C beginner. The libraries aren't ready and the best idioms have not gelled).