# Does all box2d bodies have collision detection?

Tags: c++, box2d

What I want to know is if both b2-static and dynamic bodies have automatic collision detection.

And how do I tell box2D what it should do when it collides with a specific body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow some tutorials as you are learning Box2D. Every body in Box2D has collision detection unless disabled. There are many way of checking collisions, here they're explained well:
http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy

Also do some research please, things like this can be easily found on Google or even [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/basic-box2d-collision-detection?rq=1).

Comment: Couldn't find it when I googled. Though it was probably because of my horrible English. :P